# Where to obtain Visual C++ Express runtime dlls

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, software-distribution

I want to distribute msvcr100.dll and msvcp100.dll in the application local folder along with my .exe I don't want to use the vcredist_x86.exe installer, static linking or a msm merge module.

Where can I find the correct versions of these files? VC++ Express doesn't have a \Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\redist\x86\ folder as described [on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293565%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). I'm concerned about trying to take them from \Windows\System32 in case they're the wrong version or its somehow not correct.

Comment: They are not the "wrong version", they are the version you tested your code with.

Comment: Do you have any reference showing that these are the correct files to distribute? It doesn't sound very safe. Maybe some other program installed them there.

Comment: Hans, they are the wrong version. You should not distribute the dlls that are in your system32 directory even if they are the same ones being used by your program when you test it. This is because they can be 64 bit versions which won't work on 32 bit Windows. This is true even if your application is a 32 bit application. SysWOW64 has the 32 bit versions which seem safe to use with a 32 bit application on either 32 or 64 bit Windows.