# My installation of Visual Studio 2010 Express doesn’t include a “redist” folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express and I’m building an application that needs to bundle the redistributable msvcp100 and msvcr100 libraries. The sources I’ve seen say that I should pull these files directly out of

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.CRT
```

My system has a “VC” directory in the indicated location but no “redist” directory. Furthermore, I can’t find an “msvcp100.dll” anywhere in the “Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0” directory, but there is an “msvcr100.dll” in

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\X64
```

Should these libraries exist in the first directory I mentioned? If so, any idea why they aren’t present? If not, where should I get them?

(My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23405926/where-to-obtain-visual-c-express-runtime-dlls), which didn’t receive a satisfactory answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Legally if the DLLs don't exist in the redist folder then you don't have permission to redistribute them. They're a copyrighted work and Microsoft only gives you permission under the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express licence agreement to redistribute code included with the software and listed in REDIST.TXT. The file `Common7\Packages\Debugger\X64\mscvcr100.dll` isn't listed in the REDIST.TXT file, so you don't have permission redistribute it. Same with any other DLL you find outside of the redist folder. If you download `vcredist_x86.exe` separately from Microsoft then the VC++ 2010 Express licence agreement doesn't apply to it at all, and so you're bound by the different and separate agreement included with it.

If you want to redistribute an application built with Visual C++ on a strong legal basis you have three options. The first is not to redistribute the DLLs and point your end users at Microsoft's website to download them if they don't already have them installed. The second is to upgrade to Visual C++ 2010 Professional which includes the redist directory. The third is to upgrade (or downgrade) to a version of Visual C++ Express that includes the redist directory.

Comment: So in summary, the “redist” folder isn’t *supposed* to be there, given that I’m using MSVC 2010 Express?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know if the absence of the redist folder in 2010 Express edition was intentional or accidental. Previous and subsequent Express editions included it, so it might be an accidental. However Microsoft changed how they allowed you to redistribute the DLLs in 2010. In VS 2008, regardless of edition, there were pretty restrictive requirements on redistributing the DLLs. In VS 2010 these requirements were eased, but it's possible Microsoft at the time thought they couldn't trust to redistribute the DLLs properly.